# Conditional blocks of code in linux bash

Tags: bash, conditional

Nearly everybody knows very useful && and || operators, for example:

```
rm myf && echo "File is removed successfully" || echo "File is not removed"
```

I've got a question: how to put a block of commands after && or || operators without using the function?

For example I want to do:

```
rm myf && \
  echo "File is removed successfully" \
  echo "another command executed when rm was successful" || \
  echo "File is not removed" \
  echo "another command executed when rm was NOT successful"
```

What is the proper syntax of that script?

Comment: Even if you can do this, you shouldn't.  Use a proper conditional `if/then/else` to make it much easier to read for your self or other people that have to read your script some time in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
rm myf && {
  echo "File is removed successfully" 
  echo "another command executed when rm was successful"
} || {
  echo "File is not removed" 
  echo "another command executed when rm was NOT successful"
}
```

or better

```
if  rm myf ; then
      echo "File is removed successfully" 
      echo "another command executed when rm was successful"
else
      echo "File is not removed" 
      echo "another command executed when rm was NOT successful"
fi
```

Comment: The `if` version really is better -- with `cmd && ok || fail`, it can run both `ok` and `fail` (if cmd succeeds, but `ok` finishes with an error condition).  `if` always runs either the `then` block or `else` block, never both.  Plus, it's much clearer to read.

Comment: +1 The `if` solution is also far more readable.  Making scripts readable for future use/re-use is extremely important from a pragmatic standpoint.

Comment: Do not forget to place `;` before the closing bracket if it is on one line.